# Parametrization technique in the line integral

Tags: parametrization, line-integrals

Suppose I have

$$\int_C \,(3x+y)\,\mathbb dx+(2y-x)\,\mathbb dy$$

and I want to find the line integral from the straight line $(0,1)\mapsto (2,5)$.

Most of the things I see on YouTube or some sites, most of them using parametrization $t$ with fixed interval $0<t<1$.

E.g. for my problem:

$$x : 0\mapsto 2 \Rightarrow x=2t+0\quad 0\leq t \leq 1$$

$$y : 1\mapsto 5 \Rightarrow y=4t+1\quad 0\leq t \leq 1.$$

What is the secret behind $0\leq t \leq 1$?

Then, substituting in the integral we have the following :

$$\int_0^1 \,(3(2t)+(4t+1))\,2\mathbb dt+(2(4t+1)-(2t))\,4\mathbb dt$$

Could you explain to me? Why we always have interval $0\leq t \leq 1$?

Or, it's just a coincidence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be useful to rewrite the parametrization a bit:
$$
 (x,y)  = (0,1) + t(2,4).
$$
The interpretation goes as follows: at $t=0$, the starting point is $(0,1)$. After $t$ seconds, one has moved $t$ steps in the direction $(2,4)$. So after one second $t=1$, we arrive at the end point
$$
  (0,1) + (2,4) = (2,5).
$$
Therefore, $t$ lies between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "just a coincidence" --- it's a trick folks have learned. You can certainly do the parameterization in many other ways as well. Here's the big idea:

If you write
$$
y = (1-t)A + tB
$$
then when $t = 0$, you'll have $y = A$, and when $t = 1$, you'll have $y = B$. THat's because the functions $(1-t)$ and $t$ take on particularly nice easy values (zeros and ones!) at $t = 0$ or $t = 1$, so the formula above is really easy to remember.

The cool thing is that you don't have to use individual numbers for $A$ and $B$. You could even write points, and say that 
$$
t \mapsto (1-t)(0, 1) + t(2, 5)
$$
which we interpret as
\begin{align}
t &\mapsto (1-t)(0, 1) + t(2, 5)\\
 & = (0(1-t), 1(1-t)) + (2t, 5t)\\
 & = (0, 1-t) + (2t, 5t)\\
 & = (2t, 1-t + 5t)\\
 & = (2t, 1+4t)
\end{align}
gives a path that runs from $(0, 1)$ to $(2, 5)$ as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.

And eventually, you'll learn that $A$ and $B$ can even be things like *functions*, and folks write things like
$$
H(x, t) = (1-t) \sin(x) + t \cos(x)
$$
as a way to build a function which, as $t$ varies between $0$ and $1$, varies between $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. Fortunately, that's still a little ways away from where you are now.